# Can the CloudSDK help consuming an OData entity type known only at runtime?

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk

We're developing a Cloud Foundry app with Java that should be able to consume any kind of OData entity. We get a base path from the Destination service, add some path that the user enters, and would like to store the results we get from there.

Does the Cloud SDK offer components that can help with the OData query part? Or do we need to resort to something generic like Olingo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ODataQueryBuilder` to execute arbitrary OData calls and then process the result manually.

```
ODataQueryResult result = ODataQueryBuilder
            .withEntity("/base/path/to/api" + userPath, userEntity)
            .build()
            .execute("MyDestination");
```

How you then proceed with the result depends highly on your use case. If the returned data is of a known type that you can determine at runtime, you could simply retrieve the result as that type. In this example we recieve a list of items:

```
List<MyClass> resList = result.asList(MyClass.class);
```

If not, you can process the `ResultElement`s of the request and for instance process json objects:

```
result.getResultElements().forEach(e -> {
        if( e.isResultObject() ) {
            JsonObject obj = ((GsonResultObject)e).getJsonObject();
            // do some json processing
        }
        else if( e.isResultCollection() ) {
            // do something else
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(e.getAsPrimitive());
        }
    });
```

You'll find some information on the ODataQueryBuilder in [this blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/23/sap-cloud-platform-sdk-for-service-development-create-odata-service-15-data-source-odata-v2-query-advanced/). The documentation for ResultElement can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/result/ResultElement.html).

Comment: This sounds promising. Is there some API documentation or example how to handle `ODataQueryResult`s?

Comment: I expanded my answer to include some general guidance on how to proceed with results from arbitrary OData calls. I hope this helps, a more specific answer would require more information about your specific use case.